# Visual Studio Postbuildevent Batch

Tags: visual-studio, events, batch-file, compilation

I hope someone got an idea for a little problem of mine...

I got the following Postbuild-event script in my visual-studio 2010 project:

```
copy "D:\Sources\Project/output\program.exe" "D:\Project\Testserver\"
cd "D:\Project\Testserver\"
start "" /I "D:\Project\Testserver\program.exe"
```

The program is starting properly in a new window but the build-process is not ending before I stop the batch.

The same command in a normal windows shell does create a new independent instance but visual studio seems to wait for the process to end, why? I just want it to copy and start the program and then complete the build-process, is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Oh and the follwing error is thrown in the visual studio output window:
    Error: The input redirection is not supported. Process will be killed immediately.

(I translated this from german text but still google does not find anything to this error-message)

Would be cool if someone has experience with this. Thanks!

Comment: what do you get if you just run "D:\Project\Testserver\program.exe" from a `CMD` prompt?

Comment: Then it runs my program in the console of visual-studio which is not what I wanted either. I already tried various versions with "call" "start", a batch file called with "call" and a normal start just as you said. Wether it opens my program in visual studio's output or the build process does not end before the program ends.